# Differences on these two 'isInArray' functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Which is more accurate/cross-browser compatible?

**Example 1**

```
if(!Array.isArray) {  
  Array.isArray = function (arg) {  
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) == '[object Array]';  
  };  
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

---

**Example 2**

```
function isInArray(arr,str) {
    return (arr.indexOf(str) != -1);
}
```

-I lost the source-

Comment: One of those things is not like the other :-)

Comment: hi guys, When do a question that don't make sense (like this one), I usually erase everything and put on the title 'Close Plx', but When I do this, there is always some1 who re-opens it... What should I do? help me!?

Comment: That parens in the second example are totally not needed. Also, `!==` obviously.

Comment: Well @ogps92 it's not a terrible question, floating as it is in this sea of a million other JavaScript questions,  and who knows?  Somebody might also someday have the same confusion.

Comment: @Pointy the odds of a guy comparing these apples and oranges are VERY slim.

Comment: You're probably right, but the information in the answers might be helpful to somebody wondering many different things about your subject here.

Comment: The question is not terrible, and it's got some decent answers. I don't mind keeping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do completely different things.

The first tests to see if something is an array. The second tests to see if an array contains a given object.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing apples and oranges.

The first function checks if the object *is* and array. The second function checks for a value in an array.

Answer (score 2):

These functions do different things.  The first tries to check if the variable is an array but the second checks if an element is in a given array.  The first one also probably won't be that comparable cross browser just because it uses teh literal value '[object Array]' which will probably not be the same everywhere,